# Efficient MATLAB code to find classification error

Tags: matlab

I've written a Matlab script for classification. When I execute this I'm getting Out Of Memory error.

```
for i =1:size(Y)  
    if(predictions(i) ~= clasL(find(ismember(mydata,X(i)),'rows')))  
        error = error+1;  
    end  
end
```

In the above code `Y` and `predictions` are vectors of dimension 19928. And `mydata` and `X` are 19928*62061 and 12819*62061 matrices. When I execute the following code I'm getting the following error

```
Error using  == 
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in ismember (line 62)
            tf = (a == s);

Error in myinit (line 105)
if(predictions(i) ~= clasL(find(ismember(mydata,X(i)),1)))
```

How to overcome this? Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Is `clasL` your own custom function? It's difficult or impossible to modify and fix the code to solve the memory issue without knowing what function `clasL` does. Could you edit your question and include the code of `clasL` function in it?

Comment: Sorry. clasL is another vector of dimension 19928. Basically clasL contains original class label and predictions contains predicted class label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try running ulimit on the MATLAB process so it can use as much memory as is available.

Second, I think you want to switch the order of arguments to `ismember`:

```
ismember(X(i, :), mydata, 'rows')
```

Third, you don't need the extra `find` function if you change the order of arguments. You would then simply do this (inside the loop):

```
[~, idx] = ismember(X(i, :), mydata, 'rows')
if (idx > 0 && predictions(i) ~= clasL(idx))
    error = error+1;  
end
```

Fourth, to save on time, you can run `ismember` just once for all the rows in `X` (no loop) and then find the number of errors in a vectorized manner:

```
[~, idxs] = ismember(X, mydata, 'rows')
error = sum(predictions(idxs > 0) ~= clasL(idxs > 0))
```

Comment: Thanks. I made the suggested changes and ran the algorithm. Even now I'm getting the same error.                                      `Error using  == Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in ismember (line 225)
        d = c(1:end-1,:)==c(2:end,:);     % d indicates matching entries in 2-D

Error in myinit (line 104)
[~, idxs] = ismember(X, mydata, 'rows')`

Comment: Running ulimit didn't help? Try the loop version then. If that doesn't work either, you need to run this on a machine with more memory or do some sorting of mydata then searching or something more intricate.

Comment: If that still doesn't work, split up `mydata`, run the ismember command on the parts and concatenate the results.

Comment: Thanks. Finally it worked after splitting `mydata` and running `ismember` command on parts.